# Point P such that perimeter is least

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given two points $A(-2,0)$ and $B(0,4)$ then find coordinate of point $P$ lying on the line $2x-3y=9$ so that perimeter of triangle $APB$ is least.

Doing it by traditional calculus is making calculations very complicated. Is there smart geometrical way to solve this?

Comment: The curves of constant perimeter are ellipses, and you want the unique point on the line where it's tangent to one of the ellipses. I don't see how that's any easier than using calculus directly, however.

Comment: The segment $ \ AB \ $ is fixed, so you seek to minimize the sum of the lengths $ \ AP \ $ and $ \ PB \ $ .  Hint: the oblique line can be treated as a "reflective surface"; the "optical law" angle of incidence = angle of reflection gives the shortest path from $ \ A \ $ to $ \ B \ $ via $ \ P \ $ .  You'll need some analytic geometry, but can manage without calculus (it's implicit in this "law").

Comment: http://admin.edushoppee.com/upload_docs/doubt_solution_bulk/15jm110608.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it was easy to say what might help, but a bit less simple to find a way to avoid unpleasant radicals, which are essentially the same ones you would get using path-minimization in calculus.  Here is a geometric argument that dodges them.

The big problem with a direct approach is that the lengths of $ \ AP \ $ and $ \ BP \ $ are going to be unequal, and a number of approaches still force us to determine them.  Instead, extend a line parallel to $ \ 2x \ - \ 3y \ = \ 9 \ $  that passes through $\ A \ (-2, \ 0 ) \ $ : this is $ \ y \ = \ \frac{2}{3} x \ + \ \frac{4}{3} \ $  .  This line intersects $ \ BP \ $ at a point we'll call $ \ Q \ $ .  If we designate $ \ P \ ( X, \ Y) \ = \ (X, \ \frac{2}{3}X \ - \ 3) \ $ , then the line containing $ \ BP \ $ is $ \ y \ - \ 4 \ = \ M  x \ $ , which has slope

$$ M \ = \ \frac{4 \ - \ [ \ \frac{2}{3}X \ - \ 3 \ ]}{0 \ - \ X \ } \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{3} \ - \ \frac{7}{X} \ \ . $$

The coordinates of the intersection point $ \ Q \ $ are then found from equating

$$ \frac{2}{3} x_Q \ + \ \frac{4}{3} \ = \ \left( \ \frac{2}{3} \ - \ \frac{7}{X} \ \right)  x_Q \ + \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x_Q \ = \ \frac{8X}{21} \ \ , \ \ y_Q \ = \ \frac{16X \ + \ 84}{63} \ \ . $$

(I am sparing you a certain amount of algebra in this.)

Here is where we apply the "optical law" that we minimize the length of $ \ AP \ $ plus $ \ PB \ $  by equating the angles   these segments make to the normal line to $ \ 2x \ - \ 3y \ = \ 9 \ $ .  The normal line has slope $ \ -\frac{3}{2} \ $ and is the *perpendicular bisector* of $ \ AQ \ $ when $ \Delta APQ \ $ is *isoceles* ; then the segment $ \ PM \ $ bisects $ \angle APQ \ $ , and so also $ \ \angle APB \ $ .  The midpoint $ \ M \ $ of segment $ \ AQ \ $ is

$$ \ x_M \ = \ \frac{\frac{8X}{21} \ + \ (-2)}{2} \ = \ \frac{4X}{21} \ - \ 1  \ \ , \ \ y_M \ = \ \frac{8X \ + \ 42}{63}  $$

and lies on the normal line through $ \ P \ $ , which is

$$ y \ - \ ( \ \frac{2}{3}X \ - \ 3 \ ) \ = \ -\frac{3}{2} \ (x \ - \ X ) \ \ . $$

Omitting some further algebra, after inserting

$$ y_
M \ - \ ( \ \frac{2}{3}X \ - \ 3 \ ) \ = \ -\frac{3}{2} \ (x_
M \ - \ X ) \ \ , $$

we solve for $ \ X \ $ to obtain

$$ X \ =  \ \frac{21}{17} \ \ ,  \ \ Y \ = \ -\frac{111}{51} \ \ . $$

The graph below shows the geometrical situation.

[image]

There is no symmetry in the arrangement, so there's no good reason to expect the coordinates to come out "nicely", or that there is any "easy" method.

**EDIT (added 12 March) --**

Apart from "verifying" this graphically by plotting the function for the total length $ \ AP \ + \ BP \ $ , we can confirm the exact value for $ \ X \ $ by differentiating implicitly the total length

$$ s \ = \ s_1 \ + \ s_2 \ = \ \sqrt{(X \ + \ 2)^2 + (\frac{2}{3}Y \ - \ 3)^2} \ + \ \sqrt{X^2 \ + \ ( \ [ \ \frac{2}{3}X \ - \ 3 \ ] \ - \ 4 \ )^2}  $$

to produce

$$ \frac{ds}{dX} \ = \ 0 \ = \ \frac{ds_1}{dX} \ + \ \frac{ds_2}{dX} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{ds_1}{dX} \ = \ -\frac{ds_2}{dX} \ \ ;$$

squaring the individual terms $ \ s_1 \ $ and $ \ s_2 \ $ to remove the square-roots and then differentiating, we have

$$ 2 \ s_1 \ \frac{ds_1}{dX} \ = \ 2 \ (X \ + \ 2) \ +  \ 2 \ ( \frac{2}{3}X \ - \ 3) \ \cdot \frac{2}{3} \ \ , $$
$$ 2 \ s_2 \ \frac{ds_2}{dX} \ = \ 2 \ X  \ +  \ 2 \ ( \frac{2}{3}X \ - \ 7) \ \cdot \frac{2}{3}   $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{(X \ + \ 2) \ +  \    \frac{4}{9}X \ - \ 2  }{X \ + \ ( \frac{4}{9}X \ - \ \frac{14}{3}) } \ = \ - \frac{s_1}{s_2} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left( \ \frac{\frac{13}{9}X   }{  \frac{13}{9}X \ - \ \frac{14}{3} } \   \right)^2 \ = \ \frac{(X \ + \ 2)^2 + (\frac{2}{3}Y \ - \ 3)^2}{X^2 \ + \ ( \   \frac{2}{3}X \ - \ 7 \   )^2} \ \ .  $$

With a bit of help from a computer-algebra system (WA), we obtain two real solutions, $ \ X \ = \ \frac{21}{17} \ $ and the "spurious" solution $ \ -\frac{21}{4} \ $ .  The differentiation itself isn't particularly hard; it's the algebra that requires a lot of patience...